# Unable to make Global class work properly

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.1

I keep facing to the same error at runtime again and again:

```
Cannot initialize the custom Global object (%s) (perhaps it's a wrong reference?)
In me/myapp/conf/application.conf at line 5.
application.global=common.Global
```

Where

```
package common

object Global extends GlobalSettings {
  //...
}
```

I use `Global` in a Contoller's action, by the way.

And oddly enough, if I comment out the line `application.global=common.Global` in `/conf/application.conf`

```
# application.global=common.Global
```

then the error will disappear.

I'm using `Scala 2.10.3`, `Play 2.1.3` and sbt.version=0.12.4

```
//project/build.properties
sbt.version=0.12.4


//project/Build.scala
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
  //.....
  lazy val buildSettings = Seq(
    organization := "myapp",
    version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT123",
    scalaVersion := "2.10.3"
  )
}



//project/plugins.sbt

// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository 
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.3")
```

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your `common` package is placed inside of `app` folder and/or check for typos in names. Works like a charm.

Error disappears because it's default behaviour of Play - if there's no Global object in default path it just considers that doesn't exists at all.

Comment: that's not because of that, I already solved the error. Would you mind taking a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239741/checking-a-play-current-mode-makes-an-error-occur ?

Answer (score 0):

Also may relate to this issue with circular references from app configuration calls:

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/883