# Checking a play current mode makes an error occur

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to get the current mode in Play application:

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {
  val myVal = {
    val (a, b, c) = Play.current.mode match {
      case Mode.Dev | Mode.Test => ("a", "b", "c")
      case Mode.Prod => ("d", "e", "f")
    }

    new myClass(a, b, c)
   }
}
```

The error occurs in runtime saying `Cannot initialize the custom Global object (%s) (perhaps it's a wrong reference?)` and by stacktrace I can see it happens at `val MyVal = {...`

When I remove that field from `Global` then the error will disappear.

What's wrong with that?

Comment: I have a similar problem with Global. I'm using Play 2.2.3 and Java. Just adding a static final constant in Global causes an `play.api.PlayException: Cannot init the Global object[null]`. Without the constant it's working fine.

Comment: @Kris what kind of constant is this? can you give a sample?

Comment: @biesior I just add `public static final String VERSION = Play.application().configuration().getString("application.version");`.

Comment: @Kris create a new question for this I'll give you the sample

Comment: @ biesior Done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342409

Answer (score 3):

I hardly believe that you want to do something `onStart` or `onStop`, or maybe or some other event, but not just because ;)

```scala
object Global extends GlobalSettings {
  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    // put your code here....
  }
}
```

Comment: I have trouble to understand. Why is it problematic to do something outside of the event methods?