# 'Cannot init the Global object' error after adding a final static constant to Global class

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm using Play Framework 2.2.3 with Java.

I just add a constant to my Global class:

```
public static final String VERSION = play.application().configuration().getString("application.version");
```

Then I get this error:

```
play.api.PlayException: Cannot init the Global object[null]
    at play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$$anonfun$play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance$1.apply(Application.scala:55) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
    at play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$$anonfun$play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance$1.apply(Application.scala:49) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
    at play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$class.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance(Application.scala:48) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance$lzycompute(Application.scala:399) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$globalInstance(Application.scala:399) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at play.api.WithDefaultGlobal$class.play$api$WithDefaultGlobal$$javaGlobal(Application.scala:28) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(Play.scala:68) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(Play.scala:68) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.api.Play$.current(Play.scala:68) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
    at play.api.Play.current(Play.scala) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.3]
```

Before my app was working fine. If I put this constant in any other class, my app is working fine. Only if I put it in Global I get this error. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in [this](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/883) issue pointed out, if you want to access the configuration during application startup, you should use the onStart method.

Comment: Thank you user3567830! So the underlying problem isn't that I use a static final constant, but that I try to access the Play configuration during startup?

Comment: Yes, the problem is not the constant itself, but that you try to access the configuration while the Global object is initialized, which must not happen, since initializing the Global object loads the configuration.

Comment: Okay, but since I need this constant to be global I have to put it in some other class, which is no problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Kris You could just make it a function in Global.

Comment: @m-z But I probably have the same problem with a static function in Global?